# Is there a way to make NextAuth use the /src/app directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Is there a way to specify that I want NextAuth to redirect to this directory but within the `src/app` directory as all my routes are there since the changes in Next.js 13.

Here is an example of my code:

```js
export const authOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    // ...
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin", // Custom sign-in page
  },
  callbacks: {
    // ...
  },
};
```

Comment: I don't think https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages has anything to do with app or pages router. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

To use NextAuth with the app router, create a route at `/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts` that exports `GET` and `POST` functions:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

const handler = NextAuth({ ... })

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

See the example in the docs https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app